WordPress Reinstallation Prompt After Updating XAMPP
I have installed WordPress and was in the process of setting up my site on XAMPP. I had completed about 90% of my site customization. However, after updating XAMPP and reopening my project, I am now being prompted to install WordPress again. When I reload the page, it shows the WordPress installation screen instead of my site.
Here are the steps I took and some additional information:

I was customizing my WordPress site and had completed around 90% of the setup.
I updated XAMPP to the latest version.
After the update, I reopened XAMPP and tried to access my WordPress site.
Instead of loading my site, the WordPress installation screen appears.

What I’ve Tried:

I checked the wp-config.php file to ensure the database settings are correct.
I verified that the MySQL service in XAMPP is running.
I looked into the htdocs folder to ensure my WordPress files are still there.
I checked the database in phpMyAdmin to see if my data is still intact.

Expected Result:
I expected to see my WordPress site as it was before the XAMPP update, with all my customizations intact.
Additional Information:

I am using the latest version of XAMPP.
My WordPress installation is located in the htdocs directory of XAMPP.
I have not made any changes to the wp-config.php file or the database configuration after the update.

Any advice on how to resolve this issue and recover my WordPress site would be greatly appreciated!

backup and proceed with install.
